# Matching two lists containing slightly differing float values by allowing a tolerance

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have two sorted lists containing float values. The first contains the values I am interested in (`l1`) and the second list contains values I want to search (`l2`). However, I am not looking for exact matches and I am tolerating differences based on a function. Since I have do this search very often (>>100000) and the lists can be quite large (~5000 and ~200000 elements), I am really interested in runtime. At first, I thought I could somehow use `numpy.isclose()`, but my tolerance is not fixed, but depending on the value of interest. Several nested for loops work, but are really slow. I am sure that there is some efficient way to do this.

```
#check if two floats are close enough to match
def matching(mz1, mz2):
    if abs( (1-mz1/mz2) * 1000000) <= 2:
        return True
    return False

#imagine another huge for loop around everything
l1  = [132.0317, 132.8677, 132.8862, 133.5852, 133.7507]
l2  = [132.0317, 132.0318, 132.8678, 132.8861, 132.8862, 133.5851999, 133.7500]

d = {i:[] for i in l1}
for i in l1:
    for j in l2:
        if matching(i, j):
            d[i].append(j)
```

fyi: As an alternative to the matching function, I could also create a dictionary first, mapping the values of interest from `l1` to the window `(min ,max)` I would allow. e.g. `{132.0317:(132.0314359366, 132.0319640634), ...}`, but I think checking for each value from `l2` if it lies within one of the windows from this dictionary would be even slower...

This would be how to generate the dictionary containing min/max values for each value from l1:

```
def calcMinMaxMZ(mz, delta_ppm=2):
    minmz = mz- (mz* +delta_ppm)/1000000
    maxmz = mz- (mz* -delta_ppm)/1000000
    return minmz, maxmz

minmax_d = {mz:calcMinMaxMZ(mz, delta_ppm=2) for mz in l1}
```

The result may be a dictionary like this:
`d = {132.0317: [132.0317, 132.0318], 132.8677: [132.8678], 132.8862: [132.8862, 132.8861], 133.5852: [133.5851999], 133.7507: []}` But I actually do much more, when there is a match.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is it possible for an element of `l2` to match multiple elements of `l1`?

Comment: What is the threshold for min and max? Create an l1_min array by taking away your threshold and an l1_max by adding your threshold. Then can do a search for l1_min < l2 < l1_max?

Comment: @StardustGogeta It actually may happen, but I would be okay with it.

Comment: @Godrebh Okay, I see. Perhaps you could sort each list to begin with, then for each element in `l1`, use two binary searches to find the starting and ending indices of the sublist in `l2` that contains all possible matches. Sorting is `O(nlogn)` for each list. Then, binary search is `O(nlogm)` and iterating in the range is `O(nm)` for `l1` of size `n` and `l2` of size `m`. Overall, I think sorting `l2` (with `O(mlogm)`) would be the limiting factor there.

Comment: @KenSyme The min/max values would be different for each input value. E.g. minmz = mz - (mz* +2)/1000000 and maxmz = mz - (mz* - 2)/1000000

Comment: Since the tolerance depends on the input value, is it reasonable to assume that you have an input dictionary that maps each input to the corresponding min,max range ? If so, could you provide us with an example ?

Comment: @StardustGogeta Genius! Luckily, both lists are already sorted.

Comment: As a heads up: I tried Alain T.'s answer first and it is so much faster than what I had before (and so short!). I will try Andrej Kesely's solution as well and then wait a few hours for more comments or votes, before I accept an answer. Thank you very much! You are great.

Comment: I tested Andrej Kesely's and Alain T.'s solutions and timed them on a subset of my data. (I also compared the results just to be sure.) Unsurprisingly, both are much faster than the nested for loops, but Alain T.'s solution is the fastest. Also, I found it much easier to read. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you transpose your formula to produce a range of mz2 values for a given mz1, you could use a binary search to find the first match in the sorted l2 list, then work your way up sequentially until you reach the end of the range.

```
def getRange(mz1):
    minimum = mz1/(1+2/1000000) 
    maximum = mz1/(1-2/1000000)
    return minimum,maximum

l1  = [132.0317, 132.8677, 132.8862, 133.5852, 133.7507]
l2  = [132.0317, 132.0318, 132.8678, 132.8862, 132.8861, 133.5851999, 133.7500]

l2  = sorted(l2)
from bisect import bisect_left
d = { mz1:[] for mz1 in l1 }
for mz1 in l1:
    lo,hi = getRange(mz1)
    i = bisect_left(l2,lo)
    while i < len(l2) and l2[i]<= hi:
        d[mz1].append(l2[i])
        i+=1
```

Sorting l2 will cost O(NlogN) and the dictionary creation will cost O(MlogN) where N is len(l2) and M is len(l1).  You will only be applying the tolerance/range formula M times instead of N*M times which should save a lot of processing.

Answer (score 3):

I re-implemented the for loop using `itertools`. For it working, the inputs must be sorted. For benchmark I generated 1000 items from <130.0, 135.0> for `l1` and 100_000 items from <130.0, 135.0> for `l2`:

```
from timeit import timeit
from itertools import tee
from random import uniform

#check if two floats are close enough to match
def matching(mz1, mz2):
    if abs( (1-mz1/mz2) * 1000000) <= 2:
        return True
    return False

#imagine another huge for loop around everything
l1 = sorted([uniform(130.00, 135.00) for _ in range(1000)])
l2 = sorted([uniform(130.00, 135.00) for _ in range(100_000)])

def method1():
    d = {i:[] for i in l1}
    for i in l1:
        for j in l2:
            if matching(i, j):
                d[i].append(j)
    return d

def method2():
    iter_2, last_match = tee(iter(l2))
    d = {}
    for i in l1:
        d.setdefault(i, [])
        found = False
        while True:
            j = next(iter_2, None)
            if j is None:
                break
            if matching(i, j):
                d[i].append(j)
                if not found:
                    iter_2, last_match = tee(iter_2)
                    found = True
            else:
                if found:
                    break
        iter_2, last_match = tee(last_match)
    return d

print(timeit(lambda: method1(), number=1))
print(timeit(lambda: method2(), number=1))
```

Prints:

```
16.900722101010615
0.030588202003855258
```

Answer (score 0):

Your lists are already sorted, so you can maybe use paradigm similar to the "Merge" part of MergeSort: keep track of the current element of both `idx1` and `idx2`, and when one of them is acceptable, process it and advance only that index.

```
d = {i:[] for i in l1}
idx1, idx2 = 0, 0
while idx1 < len(l1):
    while matching(l1[idx1], l2[idx2]) and idx2 < len(l2):
        d[l1[idx1]].append(l2[idx2])
        idx2 += 1
    idx1 += 1

print(d)
# {132.0317: [132.0317, 132.0318], 132.8677: [132.8678], 132.8862: [132.8862, 132.8861], 133.5852: [133.5851999], 133.7507: []}
```

this is `O(len(l1) + len(l2))`, since it executes exactly once for each element of both lists.

The big caveat here is that this never "steps back" - if the current element of `l1` matches the current element of `l2` but the *next* element of `l1` would *also* match the current element of `l2`, then the latter does not get listed. Fixing this might require adding some sort of "look-back" functionality (which would drive the complexity class up by a magnitude of `n` in the worst case, but would still be quicker than iterating through both lists repeatedly). However, it does work for your given dataset.